# Grouping numbers based on first digits and then finding min/max using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have been struggling all day with this. I wish Python were more like SQL it would be so easy for me, but I am still learning.

Basically, I just want to group numbers based on their first four digits, and then find the min and max of those numbers for each group.

Consider a dataset of doubles:

```
[VALUES]
11112222
11113333
11114444
55556666
55557777
55558888
```

and the result I want is like this:

- for all numbers begining with 1111, the minimum value is 11112222 and the maximum value is 11114444
- for all numbers begining with 5555, the minimum value is 55556666 and the maximum value is 55558888

I have considered making a layer in ArcMap from my feature class and using SQL to select from there, but I just can't figure out the query it never seems to work.

I've spent most of my time trying a search cursor, but that is not working out very well for me either as I can't seem to use where clauses correctly.

Is there anyway I can just bring in the data as a list or dictionary or something and perform everything from there?

Answer (score 1):

The query you want is *like* Value like "1111%" (% or * depending on the database).

I suggest add a field called FirstFour and calculate it to the first four digits:

```
FirstFour = left(str("Values"),4)
```

In VB, the default parser. Fairly similar in Python if you wish.

Then use [summary statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with min & max of values and case field of FirstFour.